# How to use plotregression in a subplot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm plotting a linear regression using the MATLAB function `plotregression` in this way:

```
plotregression(x, y)
```

Now, I want to plot six different regressions and plot them in subplots, as shown below:

```
subplot(2,3,1)
plotregression(x1,y1)
subplot(2,3,2)
plotregression(x2,y2)
...
```

However, this doesn't work: the `subplot` command is ignored and only the last regression plot is shown. How can I display multiple regression plots in the same window?

I would also like to set the `xlabel` and the `ylabel` manually for each regression plot. Is that possible?

Comment: 1) Have you even read the documentation on [`plotregression`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/plotregression.html)? 2) What do you want to have in the 6 subplots? The regression between `x` and `y` is just one plot.

Comment: Thanks for replying yes I have read the plotregresion which is just for a pairs of x and y but I have 6 pairs of x and y which I want to plot in a subplot but the ting is that "plotregression" in matlab for each plot opens a new figure and I can not use subplot for this function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plotregression` function creates a new figure, so it overwrites your `subplot` configuration. By calling `plotregression` multiple times, the current plot is overwritten, and so only the last regression is shown. The documentation on [`plotregression`](http://mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/plotregression.html) tells you how to create multiple plots:

> `plotregression(targs1,outs1,'name1',targs2,outs2,'name2',...)` generates multiple plots.

i.e. for two plots, this is

```
% Generate example data
x1 = 0:0.01:1;
y1 = x1 + 0.1*randn(size(x1));
x2 = -1:0.05:1;
y2 = x2 + 0.5*randn(size(x2));

% Plot regression
plotregression(x1,y1,'My first variable', x2,y2,'Another regression')
```

[image: resulting regression plot]

Internally, `plotregression` uses `subplots`, so you can change the `xlabel`s, `ylabels`, `title`s and so on for each subplot individually by making it active with the [`subplot`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) function, and calling the relevant commands:

```
subplot(1,2,1);
xlabel('This is x_1');
subplot(1,2,2);
xlabel('And this is x_2');
ylabel('\ldots and y_2');
```

Comment: Thanks hbaderts. I can't change the xlabel for all of the graph it works just for the last graph.How I can add my own xlabel and ylabel for each graph?Thanks again

Comment: Thanks a lot hbaderts.